# Outputs of tensorflow lite model look like StatefulPartitionedCall:n, what is not expected

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, transfer-learning

I need to create an object detection model to use with a raspberry pi 4 and a camera.
To do so I create a deep learning model using transfer learning based on **ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 model**.
Documentation of this model can be found here :  [model documentation ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8](https://hub.tensorflow.google.cn/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/fpnlite_640x640/)

I am using tensorflow 2.5.0 and the output model (saved_model type) is working well. When I want to test it into my jupyter book with an image, accuracy is really good.

The problem is coming when I try to transform my tensorflow model (.pb) to tensorflow lite. Conversion works but outputs are not the same as .pb model and I don't find any documentation about the 8 outputs of this .tflite model.

As you can see in documentation above, there is 8 outputs containing num_detections, detection_boxes, detection_classes, etc ... and this is working fine using tensorflow model. But when i try to interpret outputs of tensorflow lite model, outputs looks like :

```
[{'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 428,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:7',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([    1, 51150,     4]),
  'shape_signature': array([    1, 51150,     4]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 586,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:4',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1]),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 411,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:6',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([    1, 51150,     4]),
  'shape_signature': array([    1, 51150,     4]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 569,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:5',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1]),
  'shape_signature': array([1]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 657,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:1',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1, 1]),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 639,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:2',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1]),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 622,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:3',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1, 1]),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
  'index': 604,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                              'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
                              'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1]),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1]),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

What are "StatefulPartitionedCall:n" key ? and how to use it regarding the documentation ?

For information, I am using this github to start my model : [github](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi)
And with the native model it works fine but not with mine :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 219, in <module>
    if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I suppose methods to parse outputs are not the same and I really don't know how to parse them.

Thanks for your time. I spent a lot of time to understand why it doesn't works and I have to admit I am in front of a wall.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the tensor names in the original model are different than the tensor names after saving the model.
TFLite uses the names found in the saved model during conversion.

Instead you should use the SignatureDefs in TFLite which should provide a meaningful names for accessing inputs and outputs.
See full example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and back asap !

Answer (score 0):

For those who seeing similar errors when use tf2onnx.

The solution is using TF2 + tf2onnx even if the saved_model was produced by TF1.

This is because TF1 doesn't know how to deal with StatefulPartitionedCalls properly. Please refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/issues/1153#issuecomment-720726301).